# select query using nested queries in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables(say customer and details) containing following data. I need to print the details of the people who have invested maximum amount.

Customer:

```
+------+------------+--------+
| name | visited    | amount |
+------+------------+--------+
| xyz  | 2018-04-11 |    100 |
| xyz  | 2018-04-11 |   1000 |
| abc  | 2018-02-21 |    500 |
| xyz  | 2018-03-11 |    700 |
| abc  | 2018-01-24 |     50 |
+------+------------+--------+
```

Details:

```
+------+------------+
| name | detail     |
+------+------------+
| abc  | california |
| xyz  | hongkong   |
+------+------------+
```

I have found the customer who have invested the maximum amount using the query

```
select name,sum(amount) 
from (
  select name,amount 
  from customer 
  where visited >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 MONTH)
) as subtable 
group by name 
order by amount 
limit 1;
```

i have the following output

```
+------+-------------+
| name | sum(amount) |
+------+-------------+
| xyz  |        1800 |
+------+-------------+
```

now how do i find the details of xyz from details table? I need to do this all in a single query. My output must be like.

```
+------+------------+
| name | detail     |
+------+------------+
| xyz  | hongkong   |
+------+------------+
```

My stuck, how to proceed this?

Comment: If I'm formatting your query for visibility, please don't roll it back.

Comment: Which MySQL version is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.name, d.details, sum(c.amount) 
from details d
join customer c on c.name = d.name
where c.visited >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 MONTH)
group by d.name 
order by sum(c.amount) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: can you just do `USING name`, for the JOIN?

Comment: Yes, sure you could.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` to details table. I've decided to use subquery to limit the amount of rows being looked up for the join operation.

```
select c.name, d.detail
from (
  select 
    name,
    sum(amount) as sum_amount
  from customer
  where visited >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 MONTH)
  group by name
  order by sum_amount
  limit 1
) c
left join details d on c.name = d.name
```

Note that I've removed your subquery as it was superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

To get the following outputs you can write query with join like below :

Output:-

```
    +------+------------+
    | name | detail     |
    +------+------------+
    | xyz  | hongkong   |
    +------+------------+
```

Query:-

```
select d.name, d.details
from details d
join customer cust on cust.name = d.name and
    cust.visited >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 MONTH)
group by d.name 
order by sum(cust.amount) desc
limit 1;
```

If you want to print sum Amount along with that then you have to just add one more column in your select statement :

Output:-

```
    +------+------------+--------------+
    | name | detail     | sum(amount)  |
    +------+------------+--------------+
    | xyz  | hongkong   | 1800         |
    +------+------------+--------------+
```

Query:-

```
select d.name, d.details, sum(cust.amount) 
from details d
join customer cust on cust.name = d.name and
    cust.visited >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 MONTH)
group by d.name 
order by sum(cust.amount) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: If they have millions of results it probably better to do the `WHERE cust.visited >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 MONTH)` before the `JOIN` or the loading time will be painful

Comment: yes that can be added in join condition it self like 

select d.name, d.details, sum(cust.amount) 
from details d
join customer cust on cust.name = d.name and cust.visited >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 MONTH)
group by d.name 
order by sum(cust.amount) desc
limit 1;


Let me edit my answer :)